# How to choose multiple folders and open them AppleScript

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript, script

I made a script to open a folder on an online volume and I wanted it to ask how can I choose multiple folders while the prompt is open and then open them all. Every time I do that I get this error:

[image]
[image]

```
    set check to do shell script "ping -c 2 IP"
on error retVal0
    tell application "Finder" to display alert "Fehler" message "Es besteht keine Verbindung zum Internet. Bitte die Internetverbindung überprüfen und es anschließend erneut versuchen"
end try
try
    mount volume "afp://IP/technik" as user name "NAME" with password "PW"
on error retVal1
    tell application "Finder" to display alert "Fehler" message "Der Server scheint nicht erreichbar zu sein. Bitte versuche es später erneut"
end try
delay 2
set fileList to list folder "/Volumes/technik/Kunden/Bundeswehr/"
set fileChosen to choose from list fileList with invisibles and multiple selections allowed
if fileChosen is equal to false then
    display dialog "Aktion abgebrochen" buttons {"OK"}
    quit
end if
set path1 to "/Volumes/technik/Kunden/Bundeswehr/" & "/" & fileChosen
set openPath to do shell script "open " & quoted form of path1
```

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code in question and indicate which line actually throws the error? Also, you could try with a "fileChosen" whose name doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: Also note that if `fileChosen` is not false, it will be a _list_.